# Is the "How-To" tag useful?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Is there a reasonable use-case for the [how-to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to) tag?  This tag seems overly ambiguous and broad.

I suspect a majority of our site content could fall under it (it could be reasonably applied to at least 10 of the results currently on the front page, for example).  It also doesn't seem to create a useful collection of questions or increase searchability.

Barring a good explanation of its usefulness, I propose it be removed.

Comment: And I was trying my hardest to pre-empt this, too. Ah well. It's a re-link for you, but check out [this earlier Meta discussion](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/703/guide-strategy-tips-how-to-which-do-i-use) for a collection of similarly "This could apply to a lot of our stuff" tags, and some earlier thoughts.

Comment: I've been thinking of an answer for this, but all of my efforts come up with something I'd rather conclude on the more broad scale of these kind of question-classifying tags.

Comment: @Grace I had forgotten about the linked question.  Further discussion could probably be moved over there.  It is, perhaps, worth considering these tags individually on their own merits, rather than all at once though.  It may make it clearer which ones we really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This tag, among other hopeless vague or otherwise harmful tags, has been disposed of from the site.

Comment: INCLUDING MURDER?  WHY.

Answer (score 9):

I think the tag is not useful for several reasons:

- I think it's too broad. Looking at the homepage, half the questions could be considered how-to's. If a term applies to most of the site, I feel it's pointless to have as a tag: it's not telling you anything new about the question.
- I think that tags only make sense if they classify something apart from something else. So if we use [how-to](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to), should we also use tags like [what-is-this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/what-is-this), [is-this-possible](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/is-this-possible), [what-does-this-do](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/what-does-this-do), and of course [why](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/why)? I don't think the SE engine needs a mechanic to declare each question as who/what/when/where/why/how.
- Ultimately, I think a tag is useful if it helps classify a question so that interested people can browse it/search for it/find it better. I don't think anyone would want to search or browse just the "how to" questions but not the other types.

Answer (score 4):

I see no good reason for that tag, and I believe it should be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Can someone act on this and remove it?  It's so broad, you could tack it on to half the questions on the site.